# i want to apply scrolling effect like this website ( https://victoiredouy.com/ ) . in my site wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, animation, scroll, line, elementor

I'm trying to apply the scrolling animations from Victoire Douy's website (https://victoiredouy.com/) to my WordPress site using Elementor. I've been able to find some tutorials on how to do this, but I'm still having some trouble.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the following animations to work:

The animation where the logo and menu slide in from the top when the page scrolls down.
The animation where the illustrations fade in when the page scrolls down.
The animation where the shapes move and change color when the page scrolls down.
I've tried using the Elementor scroll animation feature, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to. I've also tried using some custom CSS, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

I'm using WordPress 5.8 and Elementor 3.6.
I'm not using any third-party plugins for scrolling animations.
I've tried using the following CSS properties to animate the elements:
top: This property controls the top position of the element.
opacity: This property controls the opacity of the element.
animation-name: This property specifies the name of the animation that will be applied to the element.
animation-duration: This property specifies the duration of the animation.
animation-timing-function: This property specifies the timing function of the animation.
I've also tried using the following Elementor scroll animation settings:

Animation type: Slide in
Direction: Top
Animation duration: 1 second
Animation delay: 0 seconds
I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if there's a bug in Elementor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again!